# Home Networking Issues involving FTTP (2 connections) and Powerline Adapters - Australia

Tags: networking

I have a friend that just moved to a new house here in Australia, they have FTTP through Aussie Broadband. They requested two lines instead of one with the intention the family will use one and his business will use the other.

First port from the inside FTTP box connects to their netgear router, which includes wifi and 4 ports, this is for the family. Connecting to the second port from the FTTP box works as well, which is intended for the business. The other 2 ports on the inside FTTP box are not connected as expected.

There is just the 1 account through Aussie Broadband and both ports coming out of the FTTP box registers the same IP address.

They currently have a powerline adapter which connects into the router, which is from the first port of the FTTP box. I need to use another powerline adapters (different brand) from the 2nd port of the FTTP box.

My question is, how do I know the powerlines aren't connecting to each other somehow, even though I have set it up to only pair between the 2 different brands. The first ones were paired and working fine, then I have brought in the next 2 which are a different brand and paired them both together. In theory, this would work correctly? How would I go about testing the 2 different connections since they share the same IP address anyway.

Because of the distances from the fttp box, wifi is pretty flacky and powerlines work better. They don't want to run cables.

[Network Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcNCi.png)

Comment: You should have a separate IP address on each NTD port. However, due to CGNAT, you might see the same public IP address. The best way to tell is to look at the (WAN) DHCP IP on the nearest layer 3 device attached to that port (e.g. router), rather than trying to use websites that tell you your public IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I know the powerlines aren't connecting to each other somehow

Do your powerline adapters come with PC software for configuring them?

All HomePlug AV devices can be controlled over LAN where you can just directly enter a password that becomes the "network key" used by that device, ignoring the pairing process entirely. (The key is used both for identification and for data encryption.) So use that to configure one network key on pair A, but a different key on pair B, and you're done.

If the manufacturer doesn't provide their own software, sometimes a different one's might work, especially for adapters using Qualcomm chips.

(G.hn powerline adapters are a different case, I know nothing about them.)

If nothing like that is available – just connect all four adapters near each other:

1. connect a computer to one of pair A and start e.g. a broadcast ping (such as `ping ff02::1%eth0`) or some kind of "IP scanner" app;
2. connect a different computer to one of pair B and start a packet capture (such as Wireshark or tcpdump);
3. if Wireshark on the second computer displays packets from the first, then the two adapters are indeed exchanging data.

Well, this can be simplified by just having computer 1 ping computer 2, or something like that.